# How to change dota 2 map visiblity

Tags: steam, dota-2

I want to change map visibility in Dota 2 offline mode. E.g. "explored," "all visible," etc. How can I do it in the console?

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to use console commands(may be some cheats).

First, open console command prompt. ([How to open console](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Console))

Second, use this commend

```
 -allvision
```

or

```
dota_all_vision
```

for more console command please check this link
[Dota 2 console commands](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/List_of_Console_Commands)